# ArangoDB graph options in modeling a social network

Tags: arangodb

We are building an app that is partly a social network, on top of ArangoDB. We are at the point where we need to decide how to construct our graphs, and we have some questions but we could not find something relevant in the docs.

We will be creating some relationships between the users. There will be

1. Friend request edges
2. Friend edges
3. Close friend edges
4. Block edges
5. Mute edges etc

As a **first option**, we have considered using the *SmartGraph* functionality, however we will not know in advance the users’ locations, and even if we did the user might relocate and since their location will be part of the shard key, it will be immutable (to our current understanding).

The **second option** is to create a separate *named graph* for each edge: friend request graph, friend graph, etc

The **third option** is to create a bigger *named graph* containing all the relationships (edges) and if we need a particular subset of this graph,  to use *anonymous graphs*. However we cannot find any performance data comparing small graphs with large graphs.

Given that we cannot create multiple graphs with the same edges, we have to decide a priori which solution is the most performant and stick to it, since a possible change will result in changing all AQL queries (something we want to avoid when we are near release).

Which option would be the recommended one?

Comment: Are you using ArangoDB Enterprise or the Community Edition?

Comment: @Lieblingsmensch Enterprise